# Breaking a cylinder into sections in blender

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, objects

I need to know how to cut a shape up into separate sections, for example, how can I cut a cylinder in half, so that I can animate the different sections pivot points, thus the cylinder opens out.

With a cube before I've been able to just duplicate it 7 times, however with a cylinder I need it split in half and into other smaller sections.

Comment: Also I don't want a hollow shape i need all sides for materials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do so. As you mentioned, if you really need to fill sections after cutting, I would suggest a tricky way:

1. Create a mesh that contains expected sections. Add **Solidify** modifier to this mesh, set *Thickness* to `0.00001`. You can leave other options as default;
2. Add **Boolean** modifier to cylinder, set *Operation* to **Difference**, and *Object* to the section mesh. Then press **Apply**;
3. Delete the section mesh, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into cylinder object, select all elements, <kbd>P</kbd>><kbd>By loose parts</kbd> to separate each sections apart;
4. If you want to recalculate their origins, just <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > Origin to Geometry.

[image]

**P.S.:**
In the [latest version](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.70/) (the coming 2.70), **Boolean** modifier supports ngons, which will generate better and cleaner result.